# How do Windows DLLs get linked to the MSVC runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi

ok,Let me put my question in this way.
there are two ways we can compile our libraries in VC++(our output library type)
1)A dll
2)A lib

similarly there are two ways we can define how to add additional system libraries(how we are compiling that library):
1) using _MD(this will make sure our project wil link with msvcrt.dll)
2)using _MT(this will make sure our project will link with libcmt.dll)

I just wanted to understand is there is any correlation between "our output library type" and "how we are compiling that library".
e.g if I compile my library as dll but give the option as _MT, will it work properly(after compilation)?and if yes, which system library(whether msvcrt.dll or libcmt.dll) will get associated with this.
similarly, If I compile my library as lib(static) and give the option _MD, will it work properly ? and if yes, which system library(whether msvcrt.dll or libcmt.dll) will get associated with this.

Let me know If I am still not clear with my question.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Win32, and is all to do with the MSVC runtime. Listing your confusions in a single, long paragraph is not helpful to us. Please ask a direct question, clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++ hasn't linked code with `MSVCRT.DLL` (the OS file) since I think VC6.

All versions since then have shipped their own C and C++ runtime libraries, separate from the OS, e.g. MSVCRT90.DLL matches your tag of VC2008.

Either an application or DLL project can use the runtime library either statically linked or as a DLL.  There is no `libcmt.dll`, because static linking doesn't involve a separate DLL.  The code in `libcmt.lib` gets included in your .EXE or your .DLL.

Now, working properly is another matter entirely.  I don't recommend using `dllexport` with C++ classes, or freeing memory in a different module than allocated it, but if your code does then you MUST use `/MD` and distribute the DLL.  Otherwise each module of your application would have a separate copy of the runtime library, whose objects and memory managers would not be interchangeable.  The reason I don't recommend this, is because all modules of the application also have to be compiled with the same compiler version and options... which really stinks when you have two third-party DLLs and the compiler version doesn't match between them.

Comment: msvcr80 is for VS2005, in fact. msvcr90 goes with VS2008.

Comment: **Either an application or DLL project can use the runtime library either statically linked or as a DLL. There is no libcmt.dll, because static linking doesn't involve a separate DLL.The code in libcmt.lib gets included in your .EXE or your .DLL.**  I understand that if I am compiling my library as .lib and compile it as _MT then what you say is right. My question is, If I am compiling my project as dll(my output will be mylib.dll ) and do an _MT, will still the libcmt.lib get included to it statically ?@Ben Voigt

Comment: @Martyn: Umm, yeah.  Good catch.

Comment: @pjain: You quoted the sentence where I answered that.  If you compile a DLL project with `/MT`, the code in `libcmt.lib` gets included in your .DLL.  And your DLL has its own memory manager, incompatible with the rest of the program, so memory allocated inside the DLL must be freed inside the DLL, and memory allocated outside the DLL cannot be freed inside the DLL.

Comment: yeah, I got this point after posting it :) .Thanks for your kind help.